# What is the difference between these two assembly algorithms for selection sort when used in a C++ procedure?

Tags: c++, performance, assembly, x86, selection-sort

Here is the code provided by our professor, the C++ code that will utilize the procedure from assembly

```
    // ProjectFour.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
// COSC-2425, Project 4
// ASM Procedure Linking with C++ for Selection Sort comparison
// George A. Driscoll - 5/23/2020

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

// Function prototypes for the selection sort and swap functions.
void selectionSort(int array[], int size);
void swap(int &a, int &b);

// Function prototype for the boolean isAscending function.
bool isAscending(int numbers[], int size);

// Function Prototype for the assembly language version of selection sort.
extern "C" {
    void AsmSelectionSort(int array[], int count);
}

int main()
{
    // Local Variables
    const int SIZE = 10000;
    const int REPETITIONS = 50;
    int numbers[SIZE];
    int element[SIZE];

    cout << " Selection Sort: C++ versus ASM\n\n";

    // Define the array elements. Values will range from 1 to 1000.
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        element[i] = (rand() % 1000) + 1;
    }
    cout.imbue(locale(""));
    cout << " Sample random values:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i += 256)
    {
        cout << " " << element[i];
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    // Use the C++ function to Sort the elements in the array.
    cout << " Using the C++ Selection Sort Algorithm." << endl;
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int n = 0; n < REPETITIONS; n++)
    {
        // Copy the randomly generated array.
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = element[i];
        }

        // Use the C++ version of the Selection Sort algorithm.
        selectionSort(numbers, SIZE);
    }
    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto cppDiff = end - start;
    cout << " Duration of C++ Selection Sort Algorithm for " << SIZE << " Elements: " << chrono::duration <double, milli>(cppDiff).count() << " milliseconds.\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i += 256)
    {
        cout << " " << numbers[i];
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    // Use the Assembly Language procedure to sort the elements in the array.
    cout << " Using the Assembly Language Selection Sort Algorithm." << endl;
    start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int n = 0; n < REPETITIONS; n++)
    {
        // Copy the randomly generated array.
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = element[i];
        }

        // Use the ASM version of the Selection Sort algorithm.
        AsmSelectionSort(numbers, SIZE);
    }
    end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto asmDiff = end - start;
    if (isAscending(numbers, SIZE))
    {
        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
        cout << " Duration of ASM Selection Sort Algorithm for " << SIZE << " Elements: " << chrono::duration <double, milli>(asmDiff).count() << " milliseconds.\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i += 256)
        {
            cout << " " << numbers[i];
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
        auto overallDifference = cppDiff - asmDiff;
        cout << " This is a difference of " << chrono::duration <double, milli>(overallDifference).count() << " milliseconds.\n";
        auto percentage = chrono::duration <double, milli>(overallDifference).count() / chrono::duration <double, milli>(cppDiff).count();
        if (chrono::duration <double, milli>(overallDifference).count() > 0.0)
        {
            cout << "   Your ASM version of selection sort is " << (chrono::duration <double, milli>(percentage).count() * 100.0) << "% better than the C++ version.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "   Your ASM version of selection sort is no better than the C++ version.\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "   Your ASM version of selection sort did not put the array into ascending order.\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

void selectionSort(int array[], int size)
{
    int minIndex;  // Subscript of smallest value in the scanned area.
    int minValue;  // Smallest value in the scanned area.

    // The outer loop steps through all of the array elements,
    // except the last one. The startScan variable marks the
    // position where the scan should begin.
    for (int startScan = 0; startScan < size - 1; startScan++)
    {
        // Assume the first element in the scanable area
        // is the smallest value.
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = array[startScan];

        // Scan the array, starting at the next element in the
        // scannable area, looking for the smallest value.
        for (int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
        {
            if (array[index] < minValue)
            {
                minValue = array[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }

        // Swap the element with the smallest value with the
        // first element in the scannable area.
        swap(array[minIndex], array[startScan]);
    }
}

void swap(int &a, int &b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

bool isAscending(int numbers[], int size)
{
    // Determine if array is in ascending order.
    bool result = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] > numbers[i + 1])
        {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The C++ code will utilize my assembly selection sort algorithm to compare the speed between mine and the one provided by the code in C++.

Here is the code that worked for me

```
    TITLE AsmSelectionSort Procedure (AsmSelectionSort.asm)
 .586
 .model flat,C
 AsmSelectionSort PROTO, arrayPTR:PTR DWORD, count:DWORD
 .data
 .code
 ;----------------------------------------------------------
 AsmSelectionSort PROC arrayPTR:PTR DWORD, count:DWORD
 
 
 
 ;
 ; Performs a selection sort on an array of  32-bit integers.
 ; ----------------------------------------------------------
 
 mov ecx, count
 dec ecx
 mov esi, arrayPTR
 lea edx, arrayPTR
 
 L9:
    push ecx
    or ecx, ecx
    jz L5
 
 L6:
    or ecx, ecx
    jz L3
    add edx, 4
    mov ebx, [edx]
 
    cmp [esi], ebx
    jb L2
    mov eax, [esi]
 
    mov [edx], eax
    mov [esi], ebx
 
 L2: 
    dec ecx
    jmp L6
 L3: 
 
    pop ecx
    dec ecx
    add esi, 4
 
    mov edx, esi
 
    jmp L9
 L5:
 
    jmp short omega
omega:
    ret   ; return

AsmSelectionSort ENDP
END
```

Here is the second code that I tried to make it work but I couldn't. I also find ways to make the code smaller, but it made algorithm even slower, so I am not sure why is that, I am thinking I was using memory too much and less registers, but this is the other code

```
    TITLE AsmSelectionSort Procedure (AsmSelectionSort.asm)
 .586
 .model flat,C
 AsmSelectionSort PROTO, arrayPTR:PTR DWORD, count:DWORD
 .data
 .code
 ;----------------------------------------------------------
 AsmSelectionSort PROC arrayPTR:PTR DWORD, count:DWORD
 
 
 
 ;
 ; Performs a selection sort on an array of  32-bit integers.
 ; ----------------------------------------------------------
 
 mov ecx, count
 dec ecx
 mov esi, arrayPTR
 mov edx, arrayPTR
 
 L9:
    push ecx
 
    or ecx, ecx
    jz L5
 
 L6:
    or ecx, ecx
    jz L3
    add edx, 4
    mov ebx, [edx]
 
    cmp [esi], ebx
    jb L2
    mov eax, [esi]
 
    mov [edx], eax
    mov [esi], ebx
 
 L2: 
    dec ecx
    jmp L6
 L3: 
 
    pop ecx
    dec ecx
    add esi, 4
 
    mov edx, esi
 
    jmp L9
 L5:
 
    jmp short omega
omega:
    ret   ; return

AsmSelectionSort ENDP
END
```

The only difference between the codes is the first instruction for `edx`

In the first algorithm, I used `lea edx, arrayPTR`

In the second algorithm, I used `mov edx, arrayPTR`

The first made a speed of 99.50% faster than the C++.
The second made a speed of -1,000 milliseconds, so slower than the C++ procedure

I debugged both procedures and both were doing the same thing on the C++ program, however the first algorithm was not moving the same address from `arrayPTR` on `esi` and `edx`,,,, `esi` had a different address than `edx` at the beginning of the program,,, however at the end, they both end on the same address,, so I guess is working backwards or I am not sure.

I thought that since the variable `numbers` in C++ is a pointer to an array, I could use the `mov` instruction so that the register points to the address pointed by the pointer on C++.

I honestly used `lea` just by guessing, since I thought that since numbers is a pointer on c++, which points to a memory location, why not use `lea`, since it also points to memory locations.

So, my main question is **why is the code faster on the first one than the second one by using `lea` instead of `mov` for `edx`?**

Comment: found out that i could use jbe instead jb for both of the procedures to make it run faster, but the second one is still slower I had other codes that made the second procedure about 200 to 300 milliseconds slower than c++ but I am still in question why lea points to different address than mov on the second procedure

Comment: This is finally the full code you didn't want to post for [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63045144), I guess.  Looks like you still didn't understand [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63045144/how-could-i-make-this-assembly-code-selection-sort-algorithm-2-or-3-millisecon#comment111494979_63045144) explaining why LEA is wrong (getting the address of the pointer arg on the stack).  You also load the pointer into ESI and do set EDX = ESI at the bottom of the outer loop, so only the first outer iteration uses the wrong pointer.

Comment: Your timing results are hard to understand.  You only give absolute times for version two, with the other only described as "99.5% faster than C++", so we don't know how that compares to version two.

Comment: Also, format your asm with readable indentation.  It's hard to see what jumps where when the instructions are just mixed with branch targets.  See [Checking if a number is prime in NASM Win64 Assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/204965) for a description and example of good style.

Comment: @Peter Cordes thank you for the help.  i did understand the comment that you made mentioning that masm magically uses the stack to accomodate the parameters, however from i am reading in my book, and other videos in youtube, i could be understanding things wrong but they mention that in assembly, you have to use stack manually,, so in my code i would have to push ebp, move esp, ebp,, and then subtract 4 from esp by for every parameter, and accomodate each parameter manually.  or maybe i am reading an old book.

Comment: @Peter Cordes how could the instruction lea be pointing at a different location? and even if it is, why did the code compile like it did , where the speed is 99 percent faster than the code for c++?   what is my code doing to accomodate the numbers exactly as the c++ code? the one with the lea edx, arrayptr